# How to "zip" two arrays into hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I want to "zip" two arrays into a Hash.

From:

```
['BO','BR']
['BOLIVIA','BRAZIL']
```

To:

```
{BO: 'BOLIVIA', BR:'BRAZIL'}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Your resulting hash isn't valid syntax. Did you mean `{'BO': 'BOLIVIA', 'BR':'BRAZIL'}`?

Comment: @lurker: The resulting hash *is* valid syntax, yours isn't. In a new style hash literal, the keys need to be `Symbol`s which are valid Ruby identifiers. `'BO'` is not a legal identifier (apostrophes are not allowed in an identifier).

Comment: Both are actually valid syntax, but if I "zipped" two arrays I'd expect the result to match the source.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
keys = ['BO','BR']
values = ['BOLIVIA','BRAZIL']

Hash[keys.zip(values)]
# => {"BO"=>"BOLIVIA", "BR"=>"BRAZIL"}
```

If you want symbols for keys, then:

```
Hash[keys.map(&:to_sym).zip(values)]
# => {:BO=>"BOLIVIA", :BR=>"BRAZIL"}
```

In Ruby 2.1.0 or higher, you could write these as:

```
keys.zip(values).to_h
keys.map(&:to_sym).zip(values).to_h
```

As of Ruby 2.5 you can use `.transform_keys`:

```
Hash[keys.zip(values)].transform_keys { |k| k.to_sym }
```

Comment: Biiig +1 for `to_h`. I'm not using 2.1.0 yet, but `to_h` is finally sane way to convert array of pairs to hash. `Hash#[]` method was really clunky and didn't have that Ruby feel of doing things.

Comment: You can now use `transform_keys(&:to_sym)` to convert to symbol keys.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the single `Array` of the twos, and then transpose it, and generate `Hash`:

```
keys = ['BO','BR']
values = ['BOLIVIA','BRAZIL']
Hash[[keys,values].transpose]
# => {"BO"=>"BOLIVIA", "BR"=>"BRAZIL"}
```

or for newer ruby version:

```
[keys,values].transpose.to_h
```

Comment: There is a reason to prefer `[keys, values].transpose` over `keys.zip(values)`?

Comment: out of interest, why was this downvoted? seems like a valid method to me, it may run slow for larger lists but works fine.

Comment: @toro2k that is graphically =)

Answer (score 5):

Ironically, if you just sprinkle some dots and underscores into your question, it just works:

> I want to "`zip`" two arrays in`to_h`ash

```
ary1.zip(ary2).to_h
# => { 'BO' => 'BOLIVIA', 'BR' => 'BRAZIL' }
```

Actually, you specified in your output hash that the keys should be `Symbol`s not `String`s, so we need to convert them first:

```
ary1.map(&:to_sym).zip(ary2).to_h
# => { BO: 'BOLIVIA', BR: 'BRAZIL' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite readable version would be:

```
keys = ['BO','BR']
values = ['BOLIVIA','BRAZIL']

keys.zip(values).each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), hash|
  hash[key.to_sym] = value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a zipped array and then convert the array into hash like so :

```
keys = ['BO','BR']
values = ['BOLIVIA','BRAZIL']    
array = key.zip(values) # => [['BO','BOLIVIA'],['BR','BRAZIL']]
hash = array.to_h # => {'BO' => 'BOLIVIA','BR' => 'BRAZIL'}
```